# React maxWidth percentage. How to do this?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set maxWidth to an element using percentage and I'm getting some error. Can someone help me figure out the mistake?

```
 <div style={{ maxWidth: 40% }}
```

Comment: Well, it needs to be a string, as in  `<div style={{ maxWidth: "40%" }}`. If that's not the issue, please tell us specifically what "some error" is.

Comment: edit your question with the error your getting. this will make us to understand your issue.